# Right aligned position number of a plain text document (XSLT)

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new in XSLT and XPath.
The XML is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalog.xsl"?>

<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

This is the XSL file that specifies the transformation rules for the previous one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="nl" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="cd_catalog" select="catalog/cd"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$cd_catalog">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),'&#32;',title,$nl)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the output:

```
1 Empire
2 Hide your heart
3 Hide your heart
4 Hide your heart
5 Hide your heart
6 Hide your heart
7 Hide your heart
8 Hide your heart
9 Hide your heart
10 Hide your heart
11 Hide your heart
12 Hide your heart
13 Hide your heart
```

What I want is pretty much the same as what I get, with tiny difference. I want the number before each title to be right aligned up to three spaces, like this:

```
  1 Empire
  2 Hide your heart
  3 Hide your heart
...................
 10 Hide your heart
 11 Hide your heart
...................
100 Some title here
101 Some title here
```

Of course it requires longer list of CD's, this is not a problem.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:variable name="spaces" select="translate(count(cd), '0123456789', '          ')" />
    <xsl:for-each select="cd">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($spaces, 1 + string-length(position())), position())"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Quite sophisticated method. I hope the will believe I have made up this :).
I took me some time to comprehend the algorithm. Anyway thank you Mr. Michael, you helped me a lot :)!